# Find the value of k so that the function f is continuous at the indicated point.

Tags: calculus, continuity

Find the value of $k$ so that the function $f$ is continuous at the indicated point.
$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{k\cos x}{\pi-2x},\text{if}\,\,x\ne\frac{\pi}{2}\quad\text{at} \,\,x=\frac{\pi}{2}\\3\,\, \text{if}\,\,x=\frac{\pi}{2}\end{cases}$

My solution:
I know ,a function to be continuous at a point , L.H.L=R.H.L= value of the function.So ,I have taken Left hand limit,right hand limit and value of the function at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and got $k=3\pi.$
But the answer is $k=6.$ Where am I getting wrong?
Any guidance will wholeheartedly be appreciated.Thank you[image]

Comment: Use \,\, to separate text from symbols.

Comment: Why did you change from $x$ to $h$? And why is the variable now approaching $0$?

Comment: @DavidP the method is given in my book.

Comment: That isn't right. Have a picture from the text?

Answer (score 1):

You have computed the limits if $f(x)$ as $x \to 0$ instead of limits as $x \to \frac {\pi} 2$.

By L'Hopital's Rule, $\lim_{x \to \frac {\pi} 2} \frac {k\cos x} {\pi-2x}=\lim_{x \to \frac {\pi} 2}\frac {-k\sin x} {-2}=\frac k 2$. Hence, the condition is  $\frac k 2=3$ or $k=6$.

Comment: would you enlighten me where am I getting wrong in my steps?

Comment: How can I do that if you don't tell me how you got the left hand and right hand limits? @Debrogli

Comment: I have posted my steps ma'am.

Comment: Why did you change $x \to \frac {\pi} 2$ to $x \to 0$? Whether you write $h$ or $x$ for the variable it makes no difference, so you should have $h \to \frac  {\pi} 2$. @Debrogli

Comment: If I put $x=\frac{\pi}{2} -h,$ for  left hand limit ,and replace $x\to \frac{\pi^{-}}{2}$ as $h\to 0,$ then am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot get the limit directly because you have a $\frac 0 0$ form. You have to apply L'Hopital's Rule to get the limit. @Debrogli

Comment: Applying the substitution $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-h$ will turn the denominator into $\pi -2 (\frac{\pi}{2}-h)$ which still becomes 0, not $\pi$.  When substituted correctly the numerator is also still 0.